# from grid button present in one tab I want to open other tab ,asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, asp.net-ajax, telerik-grid

A simple task I needed to do.
I have grid view in one tab in one page(multipage control) ,there are buttons in grid and on click of that button I want to write a code which selects the other tab or load the other tab
my code is very immense and a lot of things are in it ,please suggest me a technique and i will incorporate it
working asp.net 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it done by selecting properties in item click event or my RadGrid

```
 RadTabStrip1.SelectedIndex = 2;
        RadTabStrip1.SelectedTab.Enabled = true;
        RadMultiPage1.SelectedIndex=2;
```